# Соединение и работа с Базой Данных на СУБД H2

Tags: java, база-данных, h2

Что будет работать быстрее, при условии, что каждый из 10 экземпляров класса будет выполнять по 10000 sql запросов в минуту:

1. 10 экземпляров одного класса устанавливают соединение с Базой данных
   `DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/test", bd, user, pass)`
   и работают с ней через объект Statement созданный для каждого класса
2. 10 экземпляров одного класса используют одно и то же, заранее установленное соединение с БД
   `DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/test", bd, user, pass)`
   , а каждый экземпляр класса работает с БД через объект Statement созданный для каждого класса
3. 10 экземпляров одного класса используют одно и то же, заранее установленное соединение с БД
   `DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/test", bd, user, pass)`
   , и один общий объект Statement для всех 10-ти классов

Comment: Что вам мешает написать код и проверить? Не забудьте поделиться результатом.

Comment: в третьем способе явно будет сложнее сделать многопоточную обработку. Если же код не многопоточный, то вряд ли будет существенная разница (если код написан нормально).

Современные базы данных (я не знаю h2) могут нормально переваривать и десять, и сто подключений, так что не вижу разницы и в первых двух способах (я даже думаю, что драйвер может скрыть от Вас и там будет одно подключение).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы рекомендовал вариант №1, но для оптимизации соединений с базой использовать какой-нибудь "connection pool", например [Apache DBCP](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/) или [c3p0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/).
Третий вариант - однозначно "нет". Один общий Statement в десяти различных потоках черевато проблемами (кмк).

Comment: фанат [hikaricp](https://brettwooldridge.github.io/HikariCP/) врывается в тред с ождиаемым кандидатом